# how to make preview webpage application

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, preview

I want to make a simple application having only one text field and a preview button.

It should display the preview of the page in a div on the same page. Please see the blow code to get exact idea.

```
    <form method="POST" action="" id="preview-form" >
        <input type="text" id="urltopreview" name="urltopreview" />
        <input type="button" id="preview-button" value="Preview">
        <div id="preview"></div>
   </form>
```

When I insert the URL and click Preview button, it should load the preview of that page in the div (having id="preview" ) using jquery & ajax.

I tried to use php function file_get_contents() to generate preview but I get broken images.

Any idea?

Comment: very simple.. a webpage means not only the markup but all its javascript and css files with it. you should try creating an iframe in your page and set its src property to the url

Comment: yes I tried the iframe too but unable to assign src dynamically.. further more after getting preview I want to change the background image dynamically and I think IFRAME based solution will not help me.

Comment: can you add more details? php code... path for file.. file permision.

Comment: place runat="server" on iframe element. as far as change background of the website you are opening in iframe is concerned, it sounds tricky.. in order to change background you will have to inject some javascript code in the html loaded into iframe to set its background.. in my opinion different website have different ways to set background of their website.. it seems impractical to set background of some other website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an hidden Iframe and set it source to the url entered in the textbox. Then, get the content of the iframe and append it to you preview div.

```
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{

     var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
     var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

     $("#preview").html(content);

}
```

OR

To load an internal page: 
You can use the Jquery method load()

```
 $("#preview").load($('#urltopreview').val());
```

This Jquery method will not work to load external pages because ajax calls cannot retrieve external pages for security reasons. The only way to get external pages onto your page is to use an iframe, or a server side proxy that you can call with your ajax.

Comment: I want to use div instead of IFRAME because I need to change the CSS properties of preview dynamically.

Comment: I tried the provided code but the page loads with broken images, any other idea?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes I'm trying to load external pages. CAn you please guide me how can I load external pages?

Comment: No I have to use HTML, JQUERY and PHP